Recursively enumerable languages closed under operation
Are RE languages closed under p?
$$p(L) = \{w \in L | \forall a,b \in \Sigma∗ : x = ab \implies a \in L\} $$
I've been thinking this over for a while, but I feel stuck. I understand that RE languages are represented by Turing machines that do not have to halt for words not present in the language. I guess that a Turing machine checking for p(L) could just cycle endlessly because of this, but I'm not sure what does it mean for the original answer.
Can I get a hint? 
Thanks!

Let's call $M$ a program which semi-decides $L$. What is the naive way to code a program for $p(L)$? Does it still always halt if the answer is yes?

The most naive way would be checking all prefixes for each word I guess? And if the answer is yes, the machine does not necessarily halt with some words unless there is a deterministic Turing machine?

I'm assuming you meant $w$ instead of $x$ in the definition of $p(L)$.
Here's an hint: a word $w$ is in $p(L)$ if and only if all the prefixes of $w$ are in $L$. You have an algorithm $M$ that lists all the words in $L$. Can you semi-decide $p(L)$? In other words, you should write an algorithm that, given $w$, says "yes" once it realizes that $w\in p(L)$, but is not required to say anything otherwise (this new algorithm has to use $M$).
